# Are there LED lights that can work with a fluorescent ballast?

Tags: electrical, lighting, led, fluorescent, ballast

Are there LED (retrofit) lights that are compatible with a 120V 14W fluorescent ballast? Or does the ballast always have to be removed?

Comment: Have you looked at any of the "Related" questions? --->

Comment: Just about any Harper answer to any [tag:fluorescent] tagged question will have a long dissertation on the different types of LED replacement options.

Comment: There are. A quick search led me to some a couple years ago that I installed in my laundry room. Voting to close as shopping. Or as a duplicate.

Comment: Yes, they are marketed as **"Plug-and-Play"** LEDs.  Ones called "Universal" will work in both modes: plug-and-play or opposite-end ballast-bypass.  So true Freeman!

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica : Thanks for that info! My next question was going to be, how to identify them :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple types of retrofit kits.
Universal they can work with a ballast or be direct wire.
Ballast only these lamps usually have a list of ballasts that work with the LED lamps.
And direct wire only, these the ballast must be bypassed and the tombstones can not be shunted.
So yes there are some LED lamps that can work with some ballasts.

Comment: Thanks for this info.  A DIYer has to purchase things, so knowing that things exist and what they are called is just as important as technique sometimes.